# Searching for similar value in a javascript string

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript script string that looks like this

```
var name = "John Peter James";
```

Now I also have an input field

```
<input type="text" id="searchForNames" />
```

Let's assume that a user types this value in the input field

```
var inputVal = "Pe Jame";
```

And "Pe" is the begin of "Peter" and "Jame" is also the beginning of "James"

I want to search every word in the string `name` if it begins with each word in the input value, something like this

```
inputValue = "Pe Jame";  //returns true
inputValue = "Pes James"; // returns false
inputValue = "John"; //returns true
inputValue = "Joh Pete Ja"; //returns true
inputValue = "Jon Peter James"; // returns false
inputValue = "John John"//returns false
```

Comment: *I want to search every word in the string name if it begins with each word in the input value.* You seem to have misstated this, based on your examples. You seem to have wanted to say *I want to check if every word in the input is the beginning of some word in `name`*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
newInputValue = inputValue.split(' ');
newName = name.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < newInputValue.length; i++){
    newValue = newInputValue[i];
    for(var x = 0; x < newName.length; x++){
        eachName = newName[x];
        if(eachName.startsWith(newValue))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works. It returns `false` for "Pe Jame", whereas it should return true. You're exiting the loop after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the split method to make these individual parts

```
var myString = "pe jame";
var result = myString.split(" ");
```

The parameter inside spit is the delimiter

```
function stringSplit() { 
    var name = "john peter james";
    var myString = "pe jame";
    var result = myString.split(" ");
    var nameSplit = name.split(" ");
    var isTrue = false;

    for (var q = 0; q < result.length; q++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nameSplit.length; i++) {
            if (nameSplit[i].startsWith(result[q])) {
                isTrue = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                isTrue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not perfect but i do think it is close, sorry for the late reply this took some thinking.

Comment: Then what do I do next?

Comment: @torazaburo added possible solution to answer

Answer (score 0):

Just write what you mean, which is that **every** part of the input a prefix of some part of name.

```
input.split(' ').every(isPrefixInName)
```

Oops, now we have to write `isPrefixInName`. A part of the input is a prefix in `name` if there is 
**some** word which **starts with** that part of the input.

```
function isInInput(inputPart) {
  return name.split(' ').some(namePart => namePart.startsWith(inputPart));
}
```

Comment: I guess you are having some syntax errors in the function, please could you try to fix it?

Comment: @TheKingis Sorry, fixed.

Comment: But I always get a false even when it true. I did this `found = username.split(' ').every(IsInInput);` `console.log(found); `

Comment: I will come back to this when I get a chance but in the meantime it might be educational to try debugging it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex. This will help you ignore case sensitivity

```js
var arr = ["Pe Jame", "Pes James", "John", "Joh Pete Ja", "Jon Peter James", "John John"];

function searchValues() {
  var search = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
  var r = new RegExp(search.replace(/ /g, '|'), 'i');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr.filter(x => r.test(x)), null, 4)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<button onclick="searchValues()">Search</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other told, we can use RegExp to achieve this.

[JSBin here](https://output.jsbin.com/qegaye/)

The simple regex would be `/^your input here.*/`